# Generar matriz dinámicamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

No estoy muy familiarizado con Python y no se como podría hacer una matriz en donde la ponga en una posiciones definidas, otra con otras posiciones,
de este tipo donde yo le de los valores de las "K"  y me genere la matriz. ¿es posible?. Digamos que la matriz tiene muchos elementos "K" y no quiero escribirlos manualmente y solo quiero definirlos y ya es posible

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

digamos este caso que son 4 "k" solo tenga que dar los datos de las k y no tener que hacer la matriz manualmente, ¿es posible?

Answer (score 3):

Si tu matriz tiene siempre las mismas dimensiones y número de variables, realmente es tan simple como usar las variables en el propio literal de lista:

```
k1 = float(input("Ingrese valor de k1: "))
k2 = float(input("Ingrese valor de k2: "))

k = [[k1,     -k1,       0],
     [-k1,  k1 + k2,   -k2],
     [0,      -k2,      k2]]

print(k)
```

> Ingrese valor de k1: 5
>   Ingrese valor de k2: 3
>   [[5.0, -5.0, 0], [-5.0, 8.0, -3.0], [0, -3.0, 3.0]]

---

**Edición 1**

Para que sea adaptable a cualquier número de `k` podemos hacer uso de una función y llenar la diagonal principal y las dos paralelas adecuadamente en función de las `ks` proporcionadas.

Por ejemplo:

```
def gen_kmatrix(*ks):
    diagonal = [ks[0]] + [ks[i] + ks[i+1] for i in range(len(ks) - 1)]
    shape = len(ks) + 1
    k = [[0] * shape for _ in range(shape)]
    for i in range(shape - 1):
        k[i][i] = diagonal[i]
        k[i][i + 1] = k[i + 1][i] = -ks[i]
    k[-1][-1] = ks[-1]
    return k
```

> ```
> >>> k1 = 5
> >>> k2 = 3
> >>> k3 = 7
> >>> k = gen_kmatrix(k1, k2, k3)
> >>> k
> [[5, -5, 0, 0], [-5, 8, -3, 0], [0, -3, 10, -7], [0, 0, -7, 7]]
> ```

o por ejemplo, con 10 variables:

> ```
> >>> ks = [3, 2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 8, 6, 1]
> >>> k = gen_kmatrix(*ks)
> >>> k
>
> [[   3,  -3,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>  [  -3,   5,  -2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>  [   0,  -2,   7,  -5,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>  [   0,   0,  -5,  12,  -7,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>  [   0,   0,   0,  -7,  16,  -9,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>  [   0,   0,   0,   0,  -9,  20, -11,   0,   0,   0,   0],
>  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, -11,  24, -13,   0,   0,   0],
>  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, -13,  21,  -8,   0,   0],
>  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -8,  14,  -6,   0],
>  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -6,   7,  -1],
>  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  -1,   1]
>  ]
> ```

---

**Edición 2**

Si se quiere usar NumPy la idea sería en principio la misma, pero dado que NumPy permite usar slices (cortes o rebanados) para asignar valores la cosa se simplifica, pudiendo prescindir de ciclos explícitos:

```
import numpy as np


def gen_kmatrix_np(*ks):
    ks = np.array(ks)
    shape = len(ks) + 1
    k = np.zeros((shape, shape))

    # Llenamos diagonal principal
    k[0, 0] = ks[0]
    k[-1, -1] = ks[-1]
    k[np.arange(1, shape - 1), np.arange(1, shape - 1)] = ks[:-1] + ks[1:]

    # Llenamos diagonales paralelas superior e inferior
    idx1, idx2 = np.arange(1, shape), np.arange(0, shape - 1)
    k[idx1, idx2] = k[idx2, idx1] = -ks
    return k
```

> ```
> >>> gen_kmatrix_np(5, 3, 7)
>
> array([[ 5., -5.,  0.,  0.],
>        [-5.,  8., -3.,  0.],
>        [ 0., -3., 10., -7.],
>        [ 0.,  0., -7.,  7.]])
> ```

Como cabe esperar el tiempo de ejecución se reduce enormememte, por ejemplo, para 1000 ks:

> ```
> gen_kmatrix:    8.94 ms ± 58.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
> gen_kmatrix_np: 1.27 ms ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

---

**Edición 3**

Si no necesitas la primera fila ni la primera columna solo hay que modificar un poco la función para que simplemente no las genere:

```
def gen_kmatrix(*ks):
    diagonal = [ks[i] + ks[i+1] for i in range(len(ks) - 1)]
    shape = len(ks)
    k = [[0] * shape for _ in range(shape)]
    for i in range(shape - 1):
        k[i][i] = diagonal[i]
        k[i][i + 1] = k[i + 1][i] = -ks[i + 1]
    k[-1][-1] = ks[-1]
    return k
```

> ```
> >>> gen_kmatrix(5, 3, 7)
> [[ 8, -3,  0],
>  [-3, 10, -7],
>  [ 0, -7,  7]]
> ```

```
import numpy as np


def gen_kmatrix_np(*ks):
    ks = np.array(ks)
    shape = len(ks)
    k = np.zeros((shape, shape))
    idx1, idx2 = np.arange(1, shape), np.arange(shape - 1)
    # Llenamos diagonal principal
    k[-1, -1] = ks[-1]
    k[idx2, idx2] = ks[:-1] + ks[1:]

    # Llenamos diagonales paralelas superior e inferior
    k[idx1, idx2] = k[idx2, idx1] = -ks[1:]
    return k
```

> ```
> >>> gen_kmatrix_np(5, 3, 7)
>
> array([[ 8., -3.,  0.],
>        [-3., 10., -7.],
>        [ 0., -7.,  7.]])
> ```

Comment: @UselesssCat he añadido un ejemplo con NumPy, no se si será lo más eficiente pero es lo primero que se me ha ocurrido... XD

Comment: la primera edicion esta bien pero, me acabo de dar cuenta que no necesitaria toda la primera fila y la primera columna, ¿si se puede eliminar? pero que toda la demas matriz este como la que aparece completa sin eliminar ningun dato

Comment: @DanielMaldonado he añadido otra edición... XD. Si no necesitas la primer afila y columna es de hecho más simple aún.

Comment: Jajajaj, gracias ya me salvo

Answer (score 2):

**Nota: Debido a que el OP duplicó la pregunta pongo la respuesta acá**

Me pregunto si es esto lo que quieres hacer.

```
k1, k2, k3 = 1, 2, 3

k = [
    [    k1,     -k1,        0,    0],
    [   -k1, k1 + k2,      -k2,    0],
    [     0,     -k2,  k2 + k3,  -k3],
    [     0,       0,      -k3,   k3]
]

print(k)
# imprime
# [[1, -1, 0, 0], [-1, 3, -2, 0], [0, -2, 5, -3], [0, 0, -3, 3]]
```

Ahora para generar una matriz siguiendo el patrón:

```
def generateMatrix(values: list) -> list:
    # declaramos una matriz cuadrada rellena con ceros
    matrix = [
        [0 for col in range(len(values) + 1)]
        for row in range(len(values) + 1)
    ]

    # generamos los valores de acuerdo a la lista
    for i in range(len(values)):
        matrix[i][i] += values[i]
        matrix[i + 1][i + 1] += values[i]
        matrix[i][i + 1] = matrix[i + 1][i] = -values[i]

    return matrix

print(generateMatrix([1, 2, 3]))
# imprime
# [[1, -1, 0, 0], [-1, 3, -2, 0], [0, -2, 5, -3], [0, 0, -3, 3]]

# para 10 valores
print(generateMatrix([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```

La función generará el mismo resultado.

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que no necesitaria toda la primera fila y la primera columna, ¿si se puede eliminar? pero que toda la demas matriz este como la que aparece completa sin eliminar ningun dato